Must I rewrite the whole login form or can I jsut do a part
I want to convert the current loginform of wordpress with a custom one like this :
https://www.codingnepalweb.com/create-glassmorphism-login-form-html-css/
but now I see that the button , the remember me and the register link are totally on another place that on the example.
Do be as much as possible to the example , must I rewrite the whole form or can I on some way I did not find rewrite only that part of the form.
I try to make a custom plugin for this
Edit 1: One thing I wanted to change is that the remember me checkbox and the register link are just under the password input field and next to each other
Edit 2 :
I would like that the html under the input fields looks like this :
      <div class="forget">
        <label for="remember">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
          <p>Remember me</p>
        </label>
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      <div class="register">
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
      </div>
    ```

instead of the html which is used by wordpress


the philosophy of coding with wordpress is to start from the core and make little modification to approach the result you want. and on StackExchange we can help you to do these little modifications then if you have this problem, edit your question to explain what you have and the step you want to do.
